# Uppercase the second column of a text file in Unix

Tags: unix, uppercase

I have a txt file with three column. The second column is like the following (each letter is a row of the column):

1. a
2. t
3. c
4. a
5. a
6. t

I need to uppercase this second column in Unix but don't know how (it should be with the command: | tr [a-z] [A-Z]. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '{$2 = toupper($2)}1' input-file
```

It's difficult to use `tr` for this, since `tr` will indiscriminately change every character of the input.  But you could use `tr` to do the uppercasing with something like:

```
awk '{c="tr [a-z] [A-Z]"; printf "%s%c", $1, OFS;
    printf "%s", $2 | c; close c; print OFS $3}' input-file
```

or, if you're using bash and the input file is delimited by tabs:

```
paste <(cut -f 1 input) <(tr [a-z] [A-Z] < input | cut -f 2) <(cut -f 3 input)
```